# Big trouble with long table word wrapping, especially with URLs

Tags: longtable, wrap

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating,array,booktabs,siunitx,blindtext}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p}



\title{Awesome Title}%
\author{Anonymous author}%
\date{\today}%

\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\maketitle%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{*{9}{C{2cm}|}}%
\hline%
AUTHOR:&DOI:&NSR{-}Key:&REF:&TITLE:&TYPE:&URL:&X4REF:&YEAR:\\%
\hline
H.A.Tewes, A.A.Caretto, A.E.Miller, D.R.Nethaway&None&None&U.C.,    Lawrence Rad.Lab. (Berkeley and Livermore); No.6028, p.T&Excitation  functions of neutron{-}induced reactions&Report&None&(R,UCRL{-}6028{- }T,196006)&1960\\%
R.J.Prestwood, B.P.Bayhurst&10.1103/PhysRev.121.1438&1961PR08&Physical    Review; Vol.121, p.1438&(n, 2n) Excitation Functions Of Several Nuclei From 12.0To 19.8 Mev&Journal&http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.121.1438&(J,PR,121,1438,6103)&1961\\%
J.P.Butler, D.C.Santry&10.1139/v61{-}083&None&Canadian Journal of Chemistry; Vol.39, p.689&Th232(n,2n)Th231 cross section from threshold to 20.4MeV.&Journal&http://dx.doi.org/10.1139/v61{-}083&(J,CJC,39,689,1961)&1961\\%
D.R.F.Cochran, R.L.Henkel&None&None&Washington AEC Office Reports; No.1013, p.34&TH232(N,2N).&Progress Report&None&(P,WASH{-}1013,34,58)&1958\\%
H.Karius, A.Ackermann, W.Scobel&10.1088/0305{-}4616/5/5/011&1979KA14&Jour. of Physics, Part G (Nucl.and Part.Phys.); Vol.5, Issue.5, p.715&The Pre{-}Equilibrium Contribution to the (n,2n) Reactionsof 232Th and 238U&Journal&http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305{-}4616/5/5/011&(J,JP/G,5,(5),715,7905)&1979\\%
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Now, this produces an output that looks like this:
[image: page 1 of table]

My problem is that the words are not wrapping properly, help please, I've applied many other suggestions from similar questions and even tried building the thing in LuaLaTeX, but to no avail.

Comment: For the url's, you can use `\url{}` from the `url` package.  You can insert manual hyphenation points with `\-` as in `D.R.F.\,Coch\-ran`, and you can consider presenting the table in `\small` instead of `\normalsize`.  You can also insert `\allowbreak` for a non-hypenated break, as in `10.1103/\allowbreak PhysRev.\allowbreak121.1438`.

Comment: @Steven Thank you very very much. Your suggestions work great. However, is there any way to do it in a less manual fashion? The actual table is quite huge you see, I've only shown the first page.

Comment: Actually, \url works pretty good on non-url codes too.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes I found this too, I've managed to solve the problem, will type it up once I send this in to my guide.